# Java scanner issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having problems reading in a text file with java. The text file has the following format:

```
String
String
String
String

Int 
Int
Int 
Int
```

With each String and int value having a new line character at the end and a blank line in between the stings and ints. I want to save each string value into a string array but I can't quite figure out how to get the scanner to stop at the blank line. I tried various methods such as going until there is an int, going until the value of hasNext is " ", and trying to just read the strings but nothing is working. Can someone provide anyhelp?

Comment: Why don't you just read line by line?

Comment: show us the code you have so far. Also it would probably be easier to read all the lines and then disregard the ones you don't want.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so that we can perhaps fix it.

Comment: *"I tried various methods"*  Unfortunately 'dump the problem statement on a Q&A site, throw your hands up in despair & hope someone will do it for you' - rarely succeeds.

Comment: "**I tried various methods**", Can i Show them?

Comment: My apologies this was my first attempt: 

Scanner sc = new Scanner(sf);
while (sc.Next() != " "){
    cities.add(sc.next());
}



"cities" is the name of my arraylist

Comment: I also tried while(!sc.hasNextInt())

Comment: @rsay3: don't try to post code in comments as it is not formatted and unreadable. Instead edit your original post, and show your code there. You've asked questions here before, and so you should already know to show your code attempt when you first write your question. We shouldn't have to ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure from your example if you have exactly 4 `String`s and 4 `Integer`s or more, so something like the following should work:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(scanner.hasNext() && !scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    strings.add(scanner.next());
}
while(scanner.hasNextInt()) { // If you also want to store the ints
    ints.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: I don't have an exact number of either, I just used 4 for an example

Comment: Note that this solution does add a new element to the `strings` list per word and not per line (`foo bar` in one line will add two elements to the list) and that it does not work if one of the strings can be parsed as an integer (for example if a string line is `5 apples` an exception will occur).

Comment: Thanks! The strings one works but the ints does not. my file actually has lines of ints and each line itself contains 3 ints separated by a tab. Would that be the reason why this does not work for ints?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (mScanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = mScanner.nextLine();
    if (line.length() == 0)
        break;
    else
        mArrayList.add(line);//do stuff
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work a little better but when I add the values to an arraylist it only added the first value

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext ())
    {
        String s = sc.next ();
        ++count;
        System.out.println (count + ": " + s);
        if (count == 4) 
            break;
    }
    while (sc.hasNext ())
    {
        int i = sc.nextInt ();
        System.out.println (count + ": " + i);
    }
}
```

cat dat

```
Foo

Bar

Foobar

Baz

1

2

4

8
```

Test:
    cat dat | java ScanIt

```
1: Foo
2: Bar
3: Foobar
4: Baz
4: 1
4: 2
4: 4
4: 8
```

From the original question I had, as you see, a slightly different idea about the file format, but you see: I don't do anything special for newlines or empty newlines.

So the program should work for you too.